# Looping in xtend, convert from Java

Tags: java, xtend

How would this loop be done in Xtend?

```
for (char character = '\0'; character != PacketConstants.STRING_TERMINATOR; character = (char) buffer.get())
```

I have read the documentation and tried several different things, I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `for(;;)` loop in Xtend. You should use `while` loop instead:

```
var char character = 0 as char
while (character != PacketConstants.STRING_TERMINATOR) {
    character = buffer.get() as char
}
```